# Extract stream of bytes between two strings using sed in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, dd

I have a single binary file with multiple images in it. Every image area starts with an ASCII string.The problem is the bytes between the strings are not text/ASCII but plane binary bytes. 
So the binary data between "string1" and "string2" is my image-1 and so on.
How do I extract each images out in bash? may be using 'sed'?.
Please Help.

Comment: `sed`, and most of the tools available from the shell, are designed to be used with text: a.k.a. printable characters.  Of course ALL data is "binary bytes".  So the chances are even so called "binary data" will contain printable characters somewhere.  You need to extract using the length of the text header, followed by the length of the image.  You can't reliably do this by differentiating between text and non-text.

Comment: There is the possibility that the text sing is terminated by a binary zero, `0x00` if it was generated in C.  You might be able to use that to find the end of the text string.  However you still need some way of finding the length of the image, since it is likely it will contain binary zeros as part of the data.   You need to know the layout of the file and data in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl version. Put it in a file "myprog", edit the header to what you want, `chmod +x myprog`, and do `./myprog <yourdatafile`. It creates files `out1`, `out2`, etc. It assumes the file starts with the header, or you can ignore the first part.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $data = join('',<STDIN>);
my $i = 1;
my $header = "abc";
foreach my $part (split($header,$data)){
        open(OUT,">out$i");
        print OUT $header,$part;
        close(OUT);
        $i++;
}
```